# dentry_path_raw ignoring the home directory

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I wrote and lkm and I am trying to print the current dirctory but when i am on

```
/home
```

it print only

```
/
```

and for example if I am at

```
/home/daniel
```

it print only

```
/daniel
```

but if i am at /etc directory or any other directory it print the path correctly .

```
char path[100];
static int lkm_example_init(void)
{
get_fs_pwd(current->fs, &pr);

path = dentry_path_raw(pr.dentry,car,98);
printk("path:%s",path);
}
```

Comment: According to the [comment before the function](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8.7/source/fs/d_path.c#L325), `__dentry_path` function and `dentry_path_raw` which calls it "Write full pathname from the **root of the filesystem** into the buffer". It seems that on your PC you have some filesystem **mounted** to `/home`. That is why paths inside that filesystem doesn't include `/home` prefix. I don't know how to print the full path from the root filesystem until given dentry.

Comment: @Tsyvarev but if I would try to acsses file from the kernel it work fine but when i try the access it for user space with the path it printed . it doesn't works so the pwd of the function does contain the home